# What dependency is to code in build.gradle to import package 'Package io.micronaut.test.annotation'?

Tags: micronaut

I'm trying to run the example

https://guides.micronaut.io/creating-your-first-micronaut-app/guide/index.html

HelloControllerTest needs the annotation

```
@MicronautTest
```

```
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest;
```

is not supplied by the dependencies I received from 'mn create-app':

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    implementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime"
    implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    runtimeOnly "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    testAnnotationProcessor platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testAnnotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
    testImplementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine"
}
```

What completion is needed in the former dependencies ?

Peter
Dortmund Germany

Answer (score 1):

`@MicronautTest` annotation is part of this Maven artifact `io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-core`. And it is automatically linked as a dependency by artifact:

- `io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5` if you are using JUnit 5 for unit tests
- `io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock` if you are using Spock for unit tests

So if you are using JUnit 5 then you have to add this line into `dependencies` section of your *build.gradle* script:

```
testImplementation 'io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5'
```

And of course use the `@MicronautTest` annotation only in Java test classes located in the *test/java* directory.

When you are using Spock then you have to add this line into `dependencies` section of your *build.gradle* script:

```
testImplementation 'io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock'
```

And of course use the `@MicronautTest` annotation only in Groovy test classes located in the *test/groovy* directory.

Comment: gradlew test is working fine now, but junit5 still fails with

Comment: org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate condition [io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension]: @MicronautTest used on test but no bean definition for the test present. This error indicates a misconfigured build or IDE. Please add the 'micronaut-inject-java' annotation processor to your test processor path (for Java this is the testAnnotationProcessor scope, for Kotlin kaptTest and for Groovy testCompile). See the documentation for reference: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/

Comment: junit blames the missing 'micronaut-inject-java', but the line  testAnnotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java" is included in my dependencies. Where should I add it to my Processor Path, as sugested in the error message?

Comment: I followed the proposal of the former error message: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/#junit5 and tried the MathServiceTest and ran into the same error message.

Comment: Maybe the following additional Information helps: gradlew build runs into the errors of not finding: org.junit.jupiter.params.provider, io.micronaut.test.annotation and therefore not finding MicronautTest, ParameterizedTest, CsvSource. But editing MathServiceTest under eclipse works fine, the respective packages are found.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I'm trying to run an individual unit test through my JUnit eclipse plug-in.